# Kendo remote datasource and parameters

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, datasource, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call the read method but also pass in parameters. Below is my code and I can see the values are being passed but there is an error in the console:

```
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: URL + "/Read?StudentNum=" + studentNum + "AndStudentDept=" + studentDept,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    studentNum: studentNum,
                    studentDept: studentDept
                }
            },
            pageSize: 5,
            schema: {
                data: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    return response.Data.dsstudentReport.ttstudentReport;
                },
            }
        }
    });
```

```
The error is: kendo.all.js:7165 Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function

I will continue to keep looking but if anyone could help me identify where I have made a mistake, that would be greatly appreciated. I am new to Kendo and still learning.


Thanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error often occurs because there is no `model` in `schema`. Try to add it. 
For eg:

```
transport: {},
schema: {
        model: {
            id: "id",
            fields: {
                name: { type: "string" },
                isActive: { type: "boolean" },
                age: { type: "number" }
            }
        }
    }
```

It represents data structure that you are fetching with `read` method.

Ps. `schema` must be on same level as `transport`. In your case `schema` is inside `transport`

Comment: thank you! I did not notice I had placed schema inside transport, thank you for pointing that out. I have this working now based on the information you kindly provided.